# Как узнать имя элемента, который вызвал событие?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, события

У меня есть следующий код:

```
        PictureBox[] ncards = GetPictures();
        PictureBox[] ncards1 = GetPictures1();
        for (int it = 0; it <= ncards.Length - 1; it++)
        {
            ncards[it].Click += Form1_Click1;
        }

        for (int it1 = 0; it1 <= ncards.Length - 1; it1++)
        {
            ncards1[it1].Click += Form1_Click;
        }
```

Обработчик должен получить номер PictureBox'а, так как все боксы имеют один обработчик события, но sender.Name не работает. Есть идеи, товарищи?

Comment: `((PictureBox)sender).Name;` Неужели вы имели ввиду, что это не работает?

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov возвращает пустую строку

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov ну MessageBox.Show((PictureBox)sender).Name) показывает ничего

Comment: Погуглил, есть ещё такой способ `sender.GetType().GetProperties()[0].Name;`

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov пишет "Allow Drop" и все

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov я тоже гуглю, но все не работает

Comment: Так Вы проверьте что можно sender кастовать к PictureBox:  PictureBox pbox = sender as PictureBox;
  if (pbox != null){
      // use 
  }

Comment: @JaponDemon попробовал Ваш код, pbox у меня не равен null, дальше, честно сказать, не знаю, что делать

Comment: Зачем  PictureBox на  Form1_Click подписывать ? Что то Вы не то делаете совсем.

Comment: @JaponDemon у меня рисуются пикчербоксы, я написал ncards[it].Click += и Visual Studio предложил такой вариант. Он никак не связан с формой.

Comment: Если вы создавали пикчабоксы в дизайнере, то им автоматически задаётся имя. Если создавали их вручную в коде, то добавьте в свой код строку наподобие `pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1"`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо вам большое! Все заработало! Просто впервые взаимодействую с формами через код. Можете написать ответ и я его отмечу!

Comment: @JaponDemon Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во всех обработчиках событий WinForms первым параметром идёт `sender`, в котором содержится объект, у которого было вызвано событие. Он имеет тип `object` потому сперва его нужно привести к нужному типу.

Сделать это можно разными способами, как уже написали в комментариях:

```
(PictureBox)sender
sender as PictureBox
```

Второй способ выглядит несколько изящнее. Но лучше использовать первый: в случае если каст не удастся (`sender` не является `PictureBox`) мы получим сообщение об ошибке в этой же строке. Во втором способе мы получим исключение `NullReferenceException` где-то ниже по коду, в итоге будет сложнее найти источник проблемы.

---

Тип [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx), являющийся родителем всех графических компонентов WinForms, имеет свойство `Name`. При использовании дизайнера формы, в это свойство заносится то же имя, которое даётся переменной (полю).

Убедиться в этом можно, кинув какой-нибудь компонент на форму и открыв файл Form*.Designer.cs. В нём среди прочих будут строки наподобие

```
this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
```

При ручном создании контролов в коде нужно добавить аналогичную строку в свой код. После чего в обработчике события можно будет получить имя компонента из этого свойства.

На заметку: метод [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) использует это же свойство для поиска.